# In GIT, how do you remove a file delete from a commit which contains other changes?

Tags: git

I have made a GIT commit.  This commit contains several changes, including a file delete.

I have since made other commits.

All the commits have been pushed, with a pull request open for review (not yet approved or merged).

Now I would like to remove the file delete from the previous commit.  That's the *ONLY* thing I want to undo.  That is, I want to keep all the other changes in the previous commits.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have you pushed these changes or are they local only?

Comment: @HomerPlata: that's a very important question!

Comment: I am not a git ninja, but what I would do is reverse that whole commit which contained file deletion. Then amend that new commit and discard all changes except file restoration. Maybe there's a smarter way.

Comment: All the committed changes have been pushed, and a pull request has been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [you *have* pushed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42343041/in-git-how-to-undo-a-committed-file-delete-when-the-commit-contains-other-chang#comment71840705_42343041), you have already allowed the deletion to be seen by other people.

This won't prevent you from discarding this set of commits in favor of a new set, but if you do so, any of those other people who have grabbed those commits must *also* discard this set of commits in favor of a new set.

You also mentioned a *pull request* in that same comment.  A pull request is essentially an email or other communication message saying: "hey, I have some commits I have made available, please take them now."  If the people who *could* take them, *have* taken them, you are now in this problem situation.  But if they *haven't* taken them, you can attempt to retract your pull request (and maybe succeed).  If so, you are back out of the problem situation.

Thus, there are two paths to choose from:

1. retract broken pull request, replace bad set of commits with new set, and make new pull request; or
2. admit error for all time, leaving bad commits around, and make new additional commit(s) to undo the mistake(s).

The first path is the best all around *if* it's not too late.  The second path is usually the best if someone else has picked up the bad commits, although in some cases, if you can find *everyone* who has done so, and they all agree, you can have them *all* discard the bad commits and take good ones instead.

Remember, all Git repositories contain commits, and each commit forms part of the history in the repository.  Each commit has its own unique hash ID—`badf00d...` and the like—and contains the unique ID of a previous commit.  It's these chains of IDs that are the history:

```
A <- B <- C <- D   <-- master
```

The *name* `master` lets you (and Git) locate the most recent commit, which we call the *tip* of the branch.  Here, that's commit `D`, and commit `D` says "my previous commit is commit `C`".  So the name `master` "points to" `D`, and `D` points back to `C`.  `C`, of course, points back to `B`, and so on—though when we reach the very first commit ever made, it doesn't point anywhere, because it's the *first* commit.  That's how we know to stop looking.

You made some wrong commits, so let's draw a commit chain with a bad commit in it:

```
...--N              <-- origin/branch
      \
       O--X--Q--R   <-- (your pull request)
```

Here `X` is the bad commit.  We'd like to *replace* `X` with good commit `P`, which is like the bad commit, only it doesn't remove the file.  Let's not worry about *how* you make the good commit yet, but just assume you *can* make `P`:

```
...--N              <-- origin/branch
      \
       O--X--Q--R   <-- (your pull request), branch
        \
         P
```

We can't use `Q` though, because it points to `X`.  Now that we've made `P` we need to make a fixed-up `Q'` that points to `P` (and also doesn't have the file deleted).  Let's draw that:

```
...--N              <-- origin/branch
      \
       O--X--Q--R   <-- (your pull request)
        \
         P--Q'      <-- branch
```

And now we need a copy of `R` as well, which points back to `Q'` (and likewise does not have the file deleted in its snapshot):

```
...--N              <-- origin/branch
      \
       O--X--Q--R   <-- (your pull request)
        \
         P--Q'--R'  <-- branch
```

Now you can throw away your old pull request and make a new one, pointing to `R'`.

#### How to take either path

We'll start with the *second* path: admit error for all time, and just fix the mess.  That's because it's the easiest way to get to the *first* path!

Again, this is more or less what you have now:

```
...--N              <-- origin/branch
      \
       O--X--Q--R   <-- branch, (your pull request)
```

The "replace pull request" thing only works if those other people haven't already taken your bad commits ending in `R`.  If they have, you would have to get them to drop the `X-Q-R` sequence in favor of the new `P-Q'-R'` sequence.  If they can't or won't drop it, your best bet is to make a single new fix-up commit `S`.  Commit `S` simply adds the deleted file back: its snapshot is the same as that of `R` but with the file restored.  Here's how you can make `S` now.  It takes just two Git commands:

```
git checkout origin/branch -- path/to/file
```

This extracts the version of `path/to/file` from the commit to which `origin/branch` points, i.e., from commit `N`.  (Name any other commit, e.g., by its hash ID, to get the version of the file from that particular commit.)  Then:

```
# you can probably come up with a better commit message!
git commit -m "fix-up: restore accidentally-deleted file"
```

to commit the result (the `git checkout` has the side effect of "pre-adding" the commit, so we do not need a separate `git add` this time).  That makes your `S`, and now you have this:

```
...--N                 <-- origin/branch
      \
       O--X--Q--R--S   <-- branch
```

You can stop now, by making a new pull request, giving your upstream repository your new commit `S` and asking them to pull *that*.  But if they haven't pulled `R` yet, and you can *retract* your old pull request ... well:

#### "Rewriting history"

Now let's see *how* to make `P`, and then `Q'` and `R'`, given that you already have `S`.  We use an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i
```

(this assumes that `branch` has `origin/branch` set as its upstream, which it should).  That brings up your editor on a set of five `pick` commands:

```
pick 1234567 commit subject for O     # the numbers will vary
pick c0ffee1 commit subject for X     # these are the hash IDs
pick badf00d commit subject for Q     # of each commit
pick cafedad commit subject for R
pick ....... fix-up: restore accidentally-deleted file
```

Note that the last line has our commit subject from our fix-up commit `S`.  Now we move that line to come right after the `pick` command for bad commit `X`, then *change* the command on the left, replacing `pick` with `squash`:

```
pick 1234567 commit subject for O
pick c0ffee1 commit subject for X
squash ....... fix-up: restore accidentally-deleted file
pick badf00d commit subject for Q
pick cafedad commit subject for R
```

Write out this command-file and exit the editor, and `git rebase` will *combine* commit `X` with commit `S` (and give you a chance to write the resulting new commit's message).  That's the corrected commit `P`.  When you write out the new message and exit the editor again, Git will copy `Q` to `Q'` and `R` to `R'`, and now you really *do* have this:

```
...--N                <-- origin/branch
      \
       O--X--Q--R     <-- (your old pull request)
        \        \
         \        S   [abandoned]
          \
           P--Q'--R'  <-- branch
```

Note that `Q'` and `R'` have different hash IDs from `Q` and `R`: that's how Git knows they're different, and can even have them at all in the first place.  You have "rewritten history" because your branch-name `branch` now says "go look at commit `R'`", when it used to say "go look at commit `S`".  Now you really *can* discard your old pull request and make a new one, saying "please take commit `R'`".

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I will use interactive debase to "rewrite" the bad commit.  I assume the git log of the deleted file is fine, that is, even though I added the file back, its creation and original author remain unchanged, and there should no history of the accidental delete and restoration. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use `git log --diff-filter=D --summary` to get all the commits which have deleted files

Lets break this command to see how it works `--diff-filter=D` flag helps you to search for summaries mentioning `delete mode`

2. Use `git checkout $commit~1 filename` to restore the deleted file.

`$commit~1` means you should add the name of the commit. Something like `1d0c9ef6eb4e39488490543570c31c2ff594426c` where $commit is nth grandchild of the named commit - [Link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

Hope this will help

Comment: I don't​ just want to retrieve the file. I know how to do this.  What I want is to remove the file delete from that particular commit.  How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is undo the deletion, it is quit easy to handler

> 1. Find the commit id which did the deletion
> 2. Execute cmd below to checkout the file
>      `git checkout commitid filename`

After that, the file is in your working directory

Answer (score 0):

You can revert a specific commitId from your branch

```
git revert commitid
```

The commit id can be found from `gitk`

Comment: This is a bad idea if you've not pushed your code. It will introduce an extra commit cluttering up your history which is usually not what people want.

Answer (score 0):

If you've not pushed, try this:

```
git reset --soft {commit tag or hash}
```

Where {commit tag or hash} is the commit BEFORE the problematic one. You can then basically re-do the whole commit, undoing as you see fit, before committing again.

I hope you haven't pushed!